# Direct Manipulation of <Text></Text> content

Tags: react-native

During gesture I want to update text inside of  component. It doesn't work fast enough if I update state. So I want to update content of this component directly like setNativeProps. Is it possible with react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refs` to directly manipulate components.
In JSX:

```
<Text ref='myTextComponent'>Test Text</Text>
```

Then you can use:

```
doThing: function(value) {
  this.refs.myTextComponent.setNativeProps({
    opacity: value
  });
},
```

Be careful though, it is advised that you do not use this often as it can create a performance bottleneck. When used incorrectly it is also an anti-pattern against React states.

Documentation can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#content

Comment: Thanks, but with setNativeProps I can change opacity, color, and other styles but text inside component is not a style.

Comment: I'd normally use state for this. In what application is state too slow?

Comment: @Jpoliachik I want to change the text value of the component (in your example it's `Test Text`) what is its prop that I should change it? (I know I can use a disabled `TextInput` as a workaround but I look for a solution with `Text` component.)